# Aussie and Brit, resident in Oz, want to marry in UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I am Australian and my fiancee is British. We have a 6 month old son and live in Australia. We plan to marry in the UK in July 2019; as many of her family are unable to travel, we are visiting for a holiday in August 2018.

Therefore I'm hoping to register intent to marry while there, but the marriage visa is only valid for 6 months. Can i apply for another marriage visa to come back for the actual wedding ceremony next year

Comment: Please use some punctuation.

Comment: Do you plan to move to the UK after marrying there, or just to marry there and return to Australia?

Answer (score 1):

My then fiancee now wife and I did a similar thing, not in UK proper but a Crown Dependency, and had an immigration discussion with UK Immigration upon our entry to London enroute to Guernsey.

UK does require a visa for marriage in UK for non-UK residents (yourself) and from your posting it sounds like your original 6 months will end: I'd see if they will extend this - looks like they *might well* provided you weren't in residence for more than 6 months during that period (see link below) but I think it worth starting a discussion with them.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visit-guidance

Given you're commonwealth yourself, I'd think they're likely to be quite helpful.

Good luck.